# ClassCastException with PreparedStatemennt upgrading to datastax driver 4.17.0 with java 17 and spring 6 and jetty 12

Tags: cassandra, java-17, datastax-java-driver, jetty-12

Facing the above issue after upgrading application to `Java 17` with `Spring 6.0.8` and DataStax Java Driver `4.17.0` versions against Apache Cassandra® `5.0-beta1` server.

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement cannot be cast to class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.PreparedStatement (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement and com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.PreparedStatement are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @563e4951)
    at com.infinote.persistence.EntityMetaDataBasedQueryBinder.bindFindByIdQuery(EntityMetaDataBasedQueryBinder.java:161)
    at com.infinote.persistence.dao.CassandraDaoSupport.lambda$get$6(CassandraDaoSupport.java:567)
    at com.infinote.persistence.dao.CassandraDaoSupport.doWithRetry(CassandraDaoSupport.java:648)
    at com.infinote.persistence.dao.CassandraDaoSupport.get(CassandraDaoSupport.java:565)
    at com.infinote.smtp.dao.EmailConfigDao.get(EmailConfigDao.java:20)
    at com.infinote.smtp.EmailServiceImpl.get(EmailServiceImpl.java:156)
    at com.infinote.smtp.EmailServiceImpl.afterPropertiesSet(EmailServiceImpl.java:201)
```

The Below issue comes when deployoying the code in the server and the table creation step is failing. Below is the code for refence.

`CassandraDaoSupport` class invoking `bindFindByIdQuery` method present in `EntityMetaDataBasedQueryBinder`:

```
 protected <T> T get(final Class<T> entityType, final Map<String, Object> ids) {
        final EntityMetaData entityMetaData = cassandraConfiguration.getEntityMetaData(entityType);
        List<T> resultSet = doWithRetry((retry) -> {
                BoundStatement boundStatement = new EntityMetaDataBasedQueryBinder(cassandraConfiguration, entityMetaData)
                        .bindFindByIdQuery(ids, retry);
                return find(boundStatement, new EntityMetaDataBasedResultSetMapper<T>(entityMetaData));
        });
        if (resultSet.size() > 1) {
            throw new NonUniqueResultException("Multiple objects found with id " + Arrays.toString(ids.entrySet().toArray()));
        } else if (resultSet.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return resultSet.get(0);
    }
```

`EntityMetaDataBasedQueryBinder` class `bindFindByIdQuery` method:

```
 public BoundStatement bindFindByIdQuery(Map<String, ? extends Object> ids, boolean refreshCache) {
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) SimpleStatement.newInstance(String.valueOf(instance().findByIdStatement(entityMetaData, refreshCache)));
        List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FieldMetaData idField : entityMetaData.idFields()) {
            values.add(ids.get(idField.name()));
        }
        //also need to bind the client id as the last parameter
        if (entityMetaData.supportMultiTenancy()) {
            values.add(cassandraConfiguration.getCurrentClient());
        }
        return statement.bind(values.toArray());
    }
```

This is present in `QueryCache` class:

```
public PreparedStatement findByIdStatement(EntityMetaData metaData, boolean refreshCache) {
        QueryEntry queries = getQueryEntry(metaData);
        if (queries.findById == null || refreshCache) {
            queries.findById = cassandraConfiguration.getSession(metaData).prepare(metaData.findByIdStatement());
        }
        return queries.findById;
    }
```

Please help me resolve this issue @Cassandra or any one upgraded to 4+ datastax driver version

Comment: So it’s surprising that the expression `(PreparedStatement) SimpleStatement.newInstance(…)` creates a “`ClassCastException: class  …DefaultSimpleStatement cannot be cast to class …PreparedStatement`”?